# displaying the maximum price and quantity of items stored in nested list

Tags: python

I am trying to figure out a way to get the maximum price and lowest quantity from the nested list

The first number is price and the second is quantity
so 10 will be price  and 50 will be quantity in **"mouse,10,50"**

```
items=[["mouse,10,50"],["pen,20,50"],["pencil,30,30"],["sharpner,40,40"],["ruler,50,10"]]
max_price=max(items)
```

Comment: What is your desired output? `["ruler,50,10"]`?

Comment: max_price=50, lowest_qty=10

Comment: what if there is an item that has [60, 20]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `math` to assign a infinity to `lowQty` and using `split()` to get the indexed value from the elements in the list:

```
import math

items=[["mouse,10,50"],["pen,20,50"],["pencil,30,30"],["sharpner,40,40"],["ruler,50,10"]]   
maxPrice = 0
lowQty = math.inf

for elem in items:
    maxPrice = max(maxPrice, int(elem[0].split(",")[1]))
    lowQty = min(lowQty, int(elem[0].split(",")[2]))

print("max_price: {}".format(maxPrice))
print("lowest_qty: {}".format(lowQty))
```

**Shorter-version**:

```
print("max_price: {}".format(max([int(elem[0].split(",")[1]) for elem in items])))
print("lowest_qty: {}".format(min([int(elem[0].split(",")[2]) for elem in items])))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
max_price: 50
lowest_qty: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
items=[["mouse,10,50"],["pen,20,50"],["pencil,30,30"],["sharpner,40,40"],["ruler,50,10"]]
max_price = 0
min_quantity = 1000000
for item in items:
  temp = item[0].split(',')
  if int(temp[1]) > max_price:
    max_price = int(temp[1])
  if int(temp[2]) < min_quantity:
    min_quantity = int(temp[2])
print(max_price)
print(min_quantity)
```

Output

```
50
10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from operator import itemgetter    
items=[["mouse,10,50"],["pen,20,50"],["pencil,30,30"],["sharpner,40,40"],["ruler,50,10"]]
temp_list = []

for i in range(0,len(items)):
    temp_list.append(items[i][0].split(","))

reverse_sorted_element= sorted(temp_list,key=itemgetter(2),reverse = True)
max_price  = reverse_sorted_element[0][2]

sorted_element= sorted(temp_list,key=itemgetter(2))
lowest_qty  = sorted_element[0][2]

print("max_price: {}".format(max_price))
print("lowest_qty: {}".format(lowest_qty))
```

**Output**

```
max_price: 50
lowest_qty: 10
```

Comment: I don't think you should be making changes to an original solution-seeking `list`.

Comment: Ohh, I thought the guy may have made a mistake. Allow me to change the answer accordingly then.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I could think of would be:

```
items=[["mouse,10,50"],["pen,20,50"],["pencil,30,30"],["sharpner,40,40"],["ruler,50,10"]]
max_price = max([int(i[0].split(",")[1]) for i in items])
min_quantity = min([int(i[0].split(",")[2]) for i in items])

print(max_price)
print(min_quantity)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `re` and `split` on `,` char in the end like,

```
>>> import re
>>> items
[['mouse,10,50'], ['pen,20,50'], ['pencil,30,30'], ['sharpner,40,40'], ['ruler,50,10']]
>>> y = max(items, key=lambda x: map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', x[0])))
>>> y
['ruler,50,10']
>>> z = y[0].split(',')
>>> z
['ruler', '50', '10']
>>> max_price, low_qty = map(int, z[1:])
>>> max_price, low_qty
(50, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

you can put the code in a function and can pass items as its arguments

```
from math import inf as INFINITY

    items=[["mouse,10,50"],["pen,20,50"],["pencil,30,30"],["sharpner,40,40"],["ruler,50,10"]]

    max_price= 0
    min_quant = INFINITY


    for List in items:
        string = List[0]

    name,quant,price = st.split(',')
    quant,price = int(quant),int(price)

    if quant<min_quant:
        min_quant = quant

    if price > max_price:
        max_price = price

print("max price is",max_price)
print("min quant is",min_quant)
```